# Access to the internet from a firewalled server

Tags: linux, firewall, proxy

I'm trying to set up a test Docker platform at work. I need pull images, but can't do so because the test server does not have direct internet access (firewalled). There is another server that can connect to the internet, but only through a proxy. Between the test server and internet-accessible server, only a handful of ports are open. I'm thinking I could set up a tunnel between both, but not sure how.

Ports open from Test server to Internet-accessible:

```
80/tcp
111/tcp
2049/tcp
7001/tcp
7002/tcp
```

Ports open from Internet-accessible to Test:

```
22/tcp
1720/tcp
```

I have http_proxy configured in .bash_profile, on the Internet-accessible server:

```
export http_proxy=http://username:password@internet-server:8080/
```

Comment: What use is that `http_proxy` definition if port `8080` isn't accessible? Or is that the point of the question? Or is that proxy actually a third server that you haven't mentioned?

Comment: The internet-accessible server uses an authenticated proxy on port 8080. If I need to get anything from the web (eg wget) on that host, I have to use the proxy.

Comment: Just so that I'm clear;

I want to be able to use wget/curl to fetch packages on the test server, through the internet-accessible server.

Answer (score 1):

You could set up a ssh-based virtual private network using the tun network pseudo-device; `man ssh` gives an example.  If you don't have admin access on the internet-accessible server you might consider [sshuttle](https://github.com/apenwarr/sshuttle) to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I got this working.

From the server which has internet-access:

```
ssh -R any-port:proxy-ip:proxy-port user@testserver
```

Then, once I'm on the test server:

```
export http_prox=http://username:password@localhost:any-port/
```

eg:

```
ssh -R 2001:proxy-ip:8080 root@testserver

[root@testserver]# export http_proxy=http://proxyuser:proxyuser-password@localhost:2001/
[root@testserver]# export https_proxy=https://proxyuser:proxyuser-password@localhost:2001/
```